# How to populate in this case Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      email: { type: String, unique: true },
      password: String,
      notifications: [{
        notifiId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Notifications' },
        viewed: { type: Number, default: 0 }
      }],
    }));
```

How to populate `notifiId` to Notifications?

My code:

```
User
    .findOne({_id: userNotifications.userId})
    .populate({path:'notifications', match: {notificationType: 
    userNotifications.notificationType}, populate: {path: notifiId })
    .exec(function(err, user){
      if(err || !user){
        return callback(1, null);
      }
      return callback(null, user.notifications)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  notifications: {
    notifiId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Notifications' },
    viewed: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  },
```

and to find it:

```
model_Variable.findById(req.params.id).populate("notifiId").exec(function (err, 
callBack) {});
```