# How do I pass an object element in express using Mongo?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to pass a whole object from an ejs template

For example:

var schema = ... {
 Name: [{

}]
}

Comment: It would really help if you filled in some details and code in your question. It's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you can achieve it, hope that's what you ask...

```
  notifications: {
    notifiId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Notifications' },
    viewed: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  },
```

and to find it:

```
model_Variable.findById(req.params.id).populate("notifiId").exec(function (err, 
callBack) {});
```

Source: [How to populate in this case Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213749/how-to-populate-in-this-case-mongoose/51215089#51215089)